How to add numerical values ​calculated from pine Script custom strategy to "Performance Summary"
AvgLongFirstDayLabel := label.new(bar_index, low - 10, text = "出现做多信号之后X天可以盈利:" + str.tostring(LongAvgFirstDay), style=label.style_label_up, color=color.rgb(255, 110, 110), size=size.normal)

I wrote a strategy and calculated the value of "the first profit can be made on X day after the long signal appears". Now I use a label to display this label on the last K line.
I want this value to be displayed in the "Performance Summary" in the form of "Performance Summary". For example: I have now separately counted short and long positions (all can also be calculated), assuming the title is: Xth time after XX signal appears I can make a profit for the first time after a few days. Is there any method (you can also refer to the documentation) or what code I need to add to pineStrict to make the "Performance Summary" additionally display my own data?
When I used python's pandas library before, I often used "A = pd.DataFrame()" and then "A.to_csv()", but now I have migrated to tradingview due to work needs. I also want to add custom data and How should I export this data to CSV in the "Transaction List" format?

You cannot add any additional data to Performance Summary. You can either display that with a label or in a table on your chart.

Hello vitruvius, I used some Label to display my customized data in the main image. Then I used a "Premium" account to export the data of the main image to CSV on my local computer. But the data of this CSV Only (time, open,...) does not have the data of my Label. What should I do to make the exported CSV contain my data?

Unfortunately, this is not really possible. Do you want to export this for each bar or is it just a “final stats” kind of information where you need it at the end of your backtesting?

I only need a "final statistics" report at the end of the backtesting. This "final statistics" report should include my calculated data and be able to export to CSV.

As I said, it is not possible BUT you could try formatting it as a string and then send this string as an alert. Something like Trades:100|Profit:$100|Start:01.01.2020|End:01.01.2024. You can receive this as text via e-mail and then parse it and use it in Excel or similar. Some manual labor is involved but this would be one way to get custom data from Tradingview.
